# Spark Streaming tuning number of records per batch size not working after few batches?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, rdd

My spark streaming app is reading from kafka using DStream approach and I'm trying to get the batch size to process 36,000 messages in 60 seconds.

I'm consuming messages from kafka topic with 600 partitions.

- `spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition = 1`
- `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled = true`
- set my batch duration to 60 seconds when I create the `StreamingContext`

with the above configurations I'm expecting to get 36000 records per batch (600*1*60) and it is working as expected for initial few batches, but after that all the records in the topic are being dumped in to one batch.

*Note*: I'm using auto scaling cluster, do I need to set any other parameters?

[image]